# R function with multiple operators

Tags: r, binning

data ranges from -6 to 6 and I am trying to create 3 categories, however my function is not returning anyone for category 2 even though there are people present

```
FFMIBMDcopdcases$lowBMD = ifelse((FFMIBMDcopdcases$copd_Tscore >= -1) , 0,
                        ifelse((FFMIBMDcopdcases$copd_Tscore < -1), 1,
                        ifelse((FFMIBMDcopdcases$copd_Tscore <= -2.5), 2, NA)))
```

Comment: Your issue is the ordering. The conditions are checked in order, and anyone less that -2.5 is also less than -1, so the way you have things structured it's not really an *else*...

Comment: When building constructs like this, it helps to make your assignments along the number line.  Start with `Tscore <= -2.5`, then `Tscore < -1`, then `Tscore >= -1`. But using `cut` (as in the answer below) will help avoid these pitfalls

Comment: just realized you traversed the number line from right to left.  If you had used `Tscore > -2.5` in the second step and then followed up with `Tscore <= 2.5`, you would have gotten your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cut` function. Example:

```
myValues <- runif(n = 20, min = -6, max = 6)

as.numeric(as.character(cut(x = myValues, breaks = c(-Inf, -2.5, -1, Inf), labels = c(2, 1, 0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a numeric result it might be easiest to use findInterval although you will need to subtract the result from 2 to get in the inverse order ( 2 for lowest and 0 for highest)  :

```
FFMIBMDcopdcases$lowBMD = 2 - findInterval(FFMIBMDcopdcases$copd_Tscore , 
                                                      c(-Inf, -2.5, -1,  Inf) )
```